# Python - How to find all substrings with a pattern in HTML?

Tags: python, html, regex, string

I am using Python to read HTML data, but I have difficulties finding all substrings between "d:Title>**Good To Great&lt**;/d:Title>" from this HTML.

```
data = "<html><head></head><body><pre style='word-wrap': break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;
d:Title&gt;Good To Great&lt;/d:Title&gt;d:ComplianceAssetId m:null='true'/&gt;
d:Title&gt;War and Peace&lt;/d:Title&gt;/d:ComplianceAssetId m:null='false'/&gt; 
d:Title&gt;The Great Gatsby&lt;/d:Title&gt;/entry&gt;&lt;/feed&gt;</pre></body></html>"
```

Expected output:

```
['Good To Great', 'War and Peace', 'The Great Gatsby']
```

I suspect regex could be a solution but I have limited knowledge about the regex (still learning), can anyone help me with the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: hi bangbangbangbang, please look into the re package for details on the built in package. You can also google 'Dive into Python 3' where you can find a really handy book that covers basic python 3 including regex handling.

Comment: *I suspect regex could be a solution* : See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2928853) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex is `'Title&gt;([\w\s]+)&lt;/d:Title'`

[image: solution output]

Python version 3.7. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> re.findall('Title&gt;(.*)&lt;/d:Title', data)
['Good To Great', 'War and Peace', 'The Great Gatsby']
```

You can use the wildcard character `.` to find the text.

Comment: Thank you. But my output is ["Good To Great&lt;/d:Title&gt;d:ComplianceAssetId m:null='true'/&gt;d:Title&gt;War and Peace&lt;/d:Title&gt;/d:ComplianceAssetId m:null='false'/&gt; d:Title&gt;The Great Gatsby"]  Is there anyway to keep book names in the middle only?

Comment: That's strange. The parentheses should filter out the other text from the return value.

Comment: The `.*` should be `.*?` to make it ungreedy.